# Serverless deploy - Stack policy ignoring condition and blocking update::delete on all resources

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm trying to apply a very simple stack policy within my serverless.yml (which otherwise works fine), to prevent lambda aliases from being deleted - relevant portion below:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: dotnetcore3.1
  stage: ${opt:stage}
  stackName: ${self:service}  
  region: eu-west-1
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  stackPolicy:
    - Effect: Allow
      Principal: '*'
      Action: 'Update:*'
      Resource: '*'
    - Effect: Deny
      Principal: '*'
      Resource: '*'
      Action:
        - Update:Delete
      Condition:
        StringEquals:
          ResourceType:
            - AWS::Lambda::Alias
```

However, when I try to deploy, I get the following error:

> Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
>
> An error occurred: AppName - Action denied by stack policy: Statement [#1] does not allow [Update:Delete] for resource [*];.

I've followed the documentation [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml) - why does my policy block [Update:Delete] for all resources instead of just ones of type AWS::Lambda::Alias?

Answer (score 0):

Your YAML file is also showing below part of Deny.  Don't you think it should be creating an issue?

```
 - Effect: Deny
      Principal: '*'
      Resource: '*'
```

Comment: Every example I've seen online has had that as well, implying (though never outright stating, as that would be far too helpful) that the condition overrides the resource if present. In fact, leaving out either of those results in a validation error for the yml.